# Runtime 1004: method saveas of object _workbook failed

Tags: vba, excel

I have some problem with Excel macro...

When I run this script I received

> error runtime 1004: method save as of object _workbook failed

One month ago this macro worked good.... Where is the problem?

I did not do a program this script, I found it already used in the station of my old colleague, and so far has ever given no problem ....

Thanks for help

```
Sub StampaVodafone()
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim Fogliotmp As Worksheet
    Dim ContoVodafone As String
    Dim FoglioElenco As Worksheet
    Dim Percorsofile As String
    Dim PercorsoSalva As String
    Dim ValCell As Variant
    Dim strTesto As String
    strTesto = "Vuoi procedere con la stampa ?" & vbCr & "SI - Per procedere con la stampa dei dettagli telefonici" & _
             vbCr & "NO - Per andare alla procedura successiva"
    If MsgBox(strTesto, 68, "Avvio StampaVodafone") = vbYes Then
        'Procedura di stampa documenti
        i = 1
        Do
            Set Fogliotmp = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
            If UCase(Mid(Fogliotmp.Name, 1, 3)) = "TEL" Or UCase(Mid(Fogliotmp.Name, 1, 3)) = "LA " Then
                'Trovo dove sta la fine pagina
                j = 15
                ValCell = Mid(CStr(Fogliotmp.Cells(j, 1).Value), 1, 12)
                Do While (UCase(ValCell) <> "TOTALE COSTI")
                    j = j + 1
                    ValCell = Mid(CStr(Fogliotmp.Cells(j, 1).Value), 1, 12)
                Loop

                With Fogliotmp.PageSetup
                    .LeftMargin = 0
                    .RightMargin = 0
                    .TopMargin = 0
                    .BottomMargin = 0
                    .PrintArea = "$A$1:$P$" & CStr(j)
                    .LeftHeader = ""
                    .CenterHeader = ""
                    .RightHeader = ""
                    .LeftFooter = ""
                    .CenterFooter = ""
                    .RightFooter = ""
                    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
                    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
                    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
                    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
                    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.511811023622047)
                    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.511811023622047)
                    .PrintHeadings = False
                    .PrintGridlines = False
                    .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
                    .PrintQuality = 600
                    .CenterHorizontally = False
                    .CenterVertically = False
                    .Orientation = xlPortrait
                    .Draft = False
                    .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
                    .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
                    .Order = xlDownThenOver
                    .BlackAndWhite = False
                    .Zoom = False
                    .FitToPagesWide = 1
                    .FitToPagesTall = 1
                    .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
                    .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
                    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
                    .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
                    .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = False
                    .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
                    .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
                    .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
                    .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
                    .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
                    .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
                    .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
                    .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
                    .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
                    .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
                    .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
                    .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
                End With
                Application.PrintCommunication = True
                Fogliotmp.PrintOut
            End If
            i = i + 1
            Set Fogliotmp = Nothing
        Loop While (i < ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count + 1)
        MsgBox "Ho terminato di stampare", vbExclamation, "MACRO SONIA"
        'Fine procedura stampa
    End If
    '--
    strTesto = "Vuoi procedere con l'estrazione dei file XLSX da spedire agli utenti?" & vbCr & _
             "SI - Inizia la generazione dei file XLSX" & vbCr & _
             "NO - Termina la macro"
    If MsgBox(strTesto, 68, "Genera XLS") = vbYes Then
        'Inizio estrazione
        Percorsofile = "H:\Vodafone\ElencoCellEstrazione.xlsx"
        PercorsoSalva = "H:\Vodafone\Estratti\"
        ContoVodafone = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name
        '--
        Set FoglioElenco = Workbooks.Open(Percorsofile).Worksheets(1)
        '--
        i = 1
        Do
            Windows(ContoVodafone).Activate
            Set Fogliotmp = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
            If UCase(Mid(Fogliotmp.Name, 1, 3)) = "TEL" Then
                strTesto = Trim(Mid(Fogliotmp.Name, 4, Len(Fogliotmp.Name)))
                'Cerco il nome della persona
                j = 2
                ValCell = Trim(CStr(FoglioElenco.Cells(j, 1).Value))
                Do While (UCase(ValCell) <> UCase(strTesto) And UCase(ValCell) <> "END LIST")
                    j = j + 1
                    ValCell = Trim(CStr(FoglioElenco.Cells(j, 1).Value))
                Loop
                If UCase(ValCell) <> "END LIST" Then
                    'Ho il nome dell'intestatario del telefono
                    ValCell = Trim(CStr(FoglioElenco.Cells(j, 2).Value))
                    strTesto = PercorsoSalva & ValCell
                    'Salvo il documento
                     Windows(ContoVodafone).Activate
                     Sheets(Fogliotmp.Name).Select
                     Sheets(Fogliotmp.Name).Copy
                     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strTesto, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
                     ActiveWindow.Close
                     Windows(ContoVodafone).Activate
                End If
            End If
            '--
            i = i + 1
            Set Fogliotmp = Nothing
            Windows(ContoVodafone).Activate
        Loop While (i < ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count + 1)
        MsgBox "Ho terminato gli export XlsX", vbExclamation, "MACRO SONIA"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `debug.print strTesto` immediately after `strTesto = PercorsoSalva & ValCell`?

Comment: as @Jeeped said check the value of strTesto because maybe it is null when you're going to save it.

Comment: @tumisma You have any advice to solve the problem?

Comment: He just gave you advice ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should debug the value of `strTesto`. Check if it's not null and if it has the extension correct (`.xlsm`)

> TIP: [How to debug in
>   excel](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html)

Comment: Your latter approach is wrong. You are advocating a file extension of .XLSM for a file format of .XLSX. I've found that a [Workbook.SaveAs method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) ius best with a filename without an extension and leaving that aspect to the FilFormat parameter.

Comment: Ok, then delete the extension and try just with the file name. But I highly recommend you debug instead of changing the parameters

Comment: Even with that revision I do not think that 'not supplying' a folder would be appropriate. You should know where your new workbook is going to end up.

Comment: There's no need to supply a folder, it will be in the folder where your workbook is store

Comment: Again, you are wrong. It will go to whatever folder is currently holding the default folder property within that application instance of excel. It could be `thisworkbook.path` or it could be `Application.DefaultFilePath` or it could be the most recently opened folder from that application instance.

Comment: Upss, you're right. Never happened to my before. I will delete that